# show what is equal to the Legendre symbol and prove that there infinite numbers of a form

Tags: number-theory

Let prime $p>2$. Show that 
$$\left ( \frac{-2}{p} \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &, p \equiv 1 \text{ or } 3 \pmod 8 \\ 
-1 &, p \equiv 5 \text{ or } 7 \pmod 8 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
According to this conclusion, show that there are infinite primes of the form $8k+3$.

Do I have to use: $\left ( \frac{-2}{p} \right ) \equiv (-2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \pmod p$ ?
Do I have to find the relation for $p=1,3,5,7$ ? But then I would have relations $\pmod {p \neq 8}$ ,right?

Comment: You can use that since it was the original definition of Legendre symbol and then the values you find for $p=1,3,5,7$ will say exactly that:

$$
\left ( \frac{-2}{p} \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &, p \equiv 1 \text{ or } 3 \pmod 8 \\ 
-1 &, p \equiv 5 \text{ or } 7 \pmod 8 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Answer (score 3):

The classical way to do this is using Gauss lemma, which states the following: if $p$ is an odd prime and $a\neq 0\bmod p$, let $T=\{a,2a,3a,\ldots,a\frac{p-1}{2}\}\subseteq \mathbb F_p$. Now set $n=|T\cap \{\frac{p+1}{2},\ldots,p-1\}|$. Then $\left ( \frac{a}{p} \right )=(-1)^n$.

Now apply the lemma with $a=2$ to get the value of $\left ( \frac{2}{p} \right )$, which is gonna be $1$ for $p\equiv 1,7\bmod 8$ and $-1$ otherwise, and then note that $\left ( \frac{-2}{p} \right )=\left ( \frac{-1}{p} \right )\left ( \frac{2}{p} \right )$.

To prove that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 3\bmod 8$, suppose that there are only finitely many of them, say $p_1,\ldots,p_r$. Now set $N=p_1\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r$, $f(x)=x^2+2$ and look at $f(N)=N^2+2$. Then $f(N)\equiv 3 \bmod 8$. So take a prime $p\mid f(N)$. This prime must be $\equiv 1,3\bmod 8$ because $f(N)\equiv 0\bmod p$ and this means that $\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)=1$. But a product of primes $\equiv 1\bmod 8$ is $\equiv 1\bmod 8$, which shows that at least one of the primes dividing $f(N)$ is $\equiv 3\bmod 8$. On the other hand, such a prime clearly cannot belong to the set $\{p_1,\dots,p_r\}$, and the claim is proved.

Comment: Ok..I haven't get taught it yet but it sounds interesting!! And  having proven that,how can I show that there are infinite primes of the form $8k+3$ ?

Comment: @evinda I added the proof to my answer.